# Using onblur/onfocus to create a field placeholder

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to write a small script to act as a form field placeholder to cover for IEs usual lacking. New to javascript so I would really appreciate a little help. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong...

```
function replacer(){

    var infoDef = document.getElementById("info").defaultValue;
    var info = document.getElementById("info");

    info.onblur = changevalue;
    info.onfocus = changevalue;

        function changevalue()
            if (info.value = infoDef) {
                info.value = '';
            }

            else {
                info.value = infoDef;
            }
        }
}
```

And HTML:

```
<textarea name="info" id="info">Default text...</textarea>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure, but that code might work if you changed the single equals sign in the `if` statement to the proper double equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding defaultValue is a good start, but the code does need a few changes to work right. Try something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="txtarea">Default value...</textarea>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var txtarea=document.getElementById("txtarea");
txtarea.onfocus=function() {
    if (txtarea.value==txtarea.defaultValue) txtarea.value="";
}
txtarea.onblur=function() {
    if (txtarea.value=="") txtarea.value=txtarea.defaultValue;
}
```

Here is a tested and working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hv5FG/). Gotta say, if it weren't for IE, `placeholder` would be a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks D. Strout. This does indeed work. Unfortunately it only seems to do so if I have it in-page. I need to add `async="true"` to the .js call for it to work which has the unfortunate side effect of sometimes breaking the form (load order?).

Would this need to be a seperate question?

Comment: Not sure if I totally understand what you mean. Try this: run the code above in a `window.onload` block like this: `window.onload=function(){/* code above */}`

Comment: Perfect. That solved the issue.

Edit for the sake of clarity:
When using the original code in page with `<script type="text/javascript">/*code goes here*/</script>` it worked. But when using the code in my called js file - `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/js/functions.js"></script>` it didn't work unless using the `async="true"` attribute. Unfortunately using that attribute caused the entire form to break (occasionally) on page load.

Running the code within `window.onload` fixed the problem entirely.
`